# Obter valores linha tabela

Tags: jquery

Preciso obter os valores de cada linha da minha tabela. Minha tabela não tem número fixo nem de linhas e nem de colunas.

Apenas desejo os valores dos `inputs` (dentro da `td`). Os inputs possuem desejados possuem classe `quantidadeDigitada`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O ideal seria criar um array com os valores por linha. Por exemplo:

```
Valores[0] = 20.40;
Valores[1] = 20.40;
Valores[2] = 20.40;
```

Pois preciso obter os dados da seguinte forma:

```
Valores.toString() = 20.40,20.40,20.40;
```

Com isso consigo identificar a quantidade por produto me baseando na posição do `array`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Primeiro selecione seus `inputs`:

   ```
   $('.quantidadeDigitada')
   ```
2. Depois pegue suas linhas:

   ```
   .closest("tr")
   ```
3. Então mapeie cada linha a um valor:

   ```
   .map(function() {
   ```
4. Retorne o valor dos `input`s formatado como quer:

   ```
       return $(this).find("input:eq(0)").val() + "." +
              $(this).find("input:eq(1)").val();
   })
   ```
5. O resultado será um array onde cada elemento é uma linha. Por fim, junte-os com a vírgula:

   ```
   .toArray()
   .join(',')
   ```

Exemplo completo:

```js
alert(
    $('.quantidadeDigitada')
        .closest("tr")
        .map(function() {
            return $(this).find("input:eq(0)").val() + "." +
                   $(this).find("input:eq(1)").val();
        })
        .toArray()
        .join(',')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="quantidadeDigitada" value="10"></td>
    <td><input class="quantidadeDigitada" value="20"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="quantidadeDigitada" value="30"></td>
    <td><input class="quantidadeDigitada" value="40"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="quantidadeDigitada" value="50"></td>
    <td><input class="quantidadeDigitada" value="60"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: O único problema é que a minha tabela tem colunas relativas pois ela é gerada dinamicamente portando não posso fazer um apontamento a `.find("input:eq(0)")`. Eu precisaria percorrer uma linha e adicionar a cada instancia do array os valores daquela linha separados por o carácter "."

Comment: @RafaelBarbosa Então são N colunas por linha, certo? Funcionaria um `$(this).find("input").map(function() { return this.value }).toArray().join('.')`? (a mesma estratégia usada para as linhas, repetida para as colunas)

Comment: Funcionou da seguinte forma:
    $('.quantidadeDigitada')
         .closest("tr")
         .map(function () {
             return $(this).find(".quantidadeDigitada").map(function () { return this.value }).toArray().join('.')
         })
         .toArray()
         .join(',')
 );